# Linux Server not responding

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg

Server not responding when I tried to convert uploaded video file(More than 100M) into mp4 format.I am using ffmpeg converter.its taking too much time to convert video file.
can any suggest how to fix this issue.?

Answer (score 1):

the PHP-Instance, which is calling ffmpeg, stunning your Server. Its not a good idea to perform realtime Video-rendering.

i would handle this so:

- users upload there videos via php-script videos are stored in a
  folder named "toConvert"
- a cronjob parsing this folder every 5 minutes and call ffmpeg for the job
- when a job is done, make a recall to "jobReadyAction.php" for after action